# how to create multisite django with one database?

Tags: django, multisite, django-3.2

I want to create some websites on a server with one database.
my structure is:

```
main_domain.com/
main_domain.com/website1
main_domain.com/website2
.
.
main_domain.com/website_n
```

Some contents are common between websites. I use Django 3
What is best practice for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Just using the django urls sounds to be good enough practice:

```py
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('website1', viwes.website1),
    path('website2', viwes.website2),
    ...
    path('website_n', viwes.websiten),
]
```

It depends how many websites you have and how different they are. You might want to consider having the `1, 2, ..., n` as a query parameter instead if all the pages use the same content with slight alterations based on the number:

```py
path('website/<website_id>/', views.website_view),
```

Then you can grab the query parameter in your view like this:

```
def website_view(request, website_id):
     pass
```

And so pass the `website_id` to modify the content of your website like you wish. Again it depends on what your project may need, the first approach may be good enough.